# jQuery Interactive: Possible Way to Simplify Code

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am creating a small interactive that in essence is a table where the user will click on a check mark in the `<td>` on click the image will change color. After the user makes all their decisions they will click submit and that's the part that I could use some help on.

Currently my plan/idea for how to approach this is to assign an ID to all of the `<td>`'s with the table (28) the Table is sized (4x7). My idea is if I do something like ->

```
If TD1 $clicked == 1 then (true)
  TD1.css("background-color", "green");
else
  TD1.css("background-color", "red");

If TD2 $clicked == 3 then (true)
  TD2.css("background-color", "green");
else
  TD2.css("background-color", "red");

If TD3 $clicked == 2 then (true)
  TD3.css("background-color", "green");
else
  TD3.css("background-color", "red");
```

and so on...

I know that this syntax isn't 100% correct but the idea is there. So I would do this for all 28 items. What I am asking; is there a simpler approach to this that I am not seeing? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's some code

```
<table> 
<tr>
        <td>Frying</td>
        <td id="td1"><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png"     width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /></td>
        <td id="td2"><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png"     width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /></td>
<td id="td3"><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png"     width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /></td>
<td id="td4"><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png"     width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /></td>
<td id="td5"><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png"     width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /></td>
<td id="td6"><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png"     width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /></td>
<td id="td7"><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png"     width="30" height="30" /><img src="img/check.png" width="30" height="30" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

In the jQuery there will be an onclick event for the img which will change it to a highlighted version of it.

There's more to the table than this one row but the end result is when the user clicks through everything they will click a submit button. Once clicked then each box would be checked to see if it is correct, if it is then background change to green, if not then red. So td1 might be equal to (clicked = 1) while td2 is equal to (clicked = 2).

Sorry that I didn't give enough info before, still pretty new here.

Comment: You could probably skip the if completely and do $(this).css(...).siblings().css(...)

Comment: @KevinB Wouldn't that approach only allow one selection?  Eg: TD1 is clicked -> green background -> all other tds -> red background.

Comment: @Justin It's far from a complete solution, there's not enough information in the question for a complete solution. toggleClass is probably more appropriate though.

Comment: The aspect that I'm not sure came across very well is that certain <td>'s have a value of 1 while others have a value of 2 or 3. Possibly have a specific class attached to these divs?

Comment: @Jobokai Do you have any actual code to show?

Comment: It looks like you do the same thing for all values. Are there some values that will behave differently?

Comment: @Jobokai I'm trying to find where the values of '1 2 3' come into play

Comment: Ok just updated the code more. I haven't actually started digging into the jQuery because I figured there had to be a better way. @Justin The 1 2 3 is coming from how many check marks (the image) are clicked. Certain <td>'s only have 1 check mark while others have 2 or 3. Does this help?

Comment: Is there any reason to not have each image in it's own `td`? I think that would make things a lot simpler for you.

Comment: @colestrode I could, my reasoning was to have all 3 grouped together inside of one. I'm open to any options. What were you thinking if they were each in their own <td>?

Comment: It's probably going to make things easier to keep track of the state of one image rather than 3. If you are using the `td`'s for grouping, you could wrap every image in a `span` instead. My answer below would still apply in that case.

Comment: @colestrode keeping track of the state is trivial `$('.checkbox').click(function(){ ($(this).hasClass('selected')) ? $(this).prop('src', 'no-check.jpg').removeClass('selected') : $(this).prop('src', 'check.jpg').addClass('selected');});`  This assumes the images have the class `checkbox` assigned to them.

Comment: @Jobokai I'm keep trying to think of a good way to accomplish this, but short of adding an additional attribute to the img tags, there really isn't a good way to determine which is 'checked', not without being overly complicated that is.  Also, you use checkboxes but it seems like you only want the user selecting a single one, which radio buttons are more suited for.

Comment: @Justin that's what I was afraid of. I guess overly complicated is the route to go. Unfortunately radio buttons are not going to work for what I need it to look like, even though they would definitely work perfect. Oh well thought I'd get some advice from others who are much smarter than me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign all the "clickable" elements the same class, and register a listener for that class with jQuery that will toggle the styling (red or green). You could also just add a listener to all `td` elements, but you might accidentally select elements you don't intend to make clickable.

Use CSS for the red/green styling.

CSS

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).is('.red')) {
        $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('green').addClass('red');
    }
});
```

Comment: that entire if statement can be condensed to `$(this).toggleClass("red green")` assuming they all have one or the other by default.

Comment: If each of the `td`'s start out being either `red` or `green` then you're right. Otherwise you would add or remove both classes every time.

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways, but I would do something like this.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="0"/>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="1"/>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="2"/>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
$(function () {
    $("input").on('click', function () {
        $(this).is(':checked') ?
            $(this).parent().css("background-color", colors[$(this).attr('name')]) :
            $(this).parent().css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PXEt9/